# How to add more custom filters in datatables request?

Tags: laravel, datatables

in my laravel 8 app with jquery 3.4/bootstrap 4.6 I use dataTable 1.10.19
and I try to add more custom filters and when user enter in search input:

```
@section('footerscripts')
    <script src="{!!admin_assets!!}/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        var oTable= null
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initEducations()

            ...
            
            function initEducations() {
                var filter_education_category_id = $("#filter_education_category_id").val()

                var filter_document_type = $("#filter_document_type").val()

            var url= 'educations_filter/1/'+filter_education_category_id + '/'+filter_document_type

                oTable = $('#tzdatatables').dataTable({
                    "language": {
                        "emptyTable": "No educations found"
                    },
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": url,
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "aoColumns": [{
                        "mData": 0 // Sr No
                    }, {
                        "sWidth": "30%",
                        "mData": 1 // Name
                    }, {
                        "mData": 2 // Status label
                    }, {
                        "mData": 3 // Education category
                    }, {
                        "mData": 4 // $created_at_formatted
                    }, {
```

But it does not work as if filter_education_category_id selected it is not applied to filter.

**MODIFIED :**
With

```
   "bServerSide": true,
```

when I enter some text in search field, ex 'a'
I see next sql traced :

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `education` 
    WHERE `education`.`title` like '%a%' 
    ORDER BY `education`.`created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

I need when non zero option in filter_education_category_id is selected (ex ‘5’) to have filter condition added, like :

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM `education` 
    WHERE `education`.`title` like '%a%' and `education`.`category_id` = ‘5’
    ORDER BY `education`.`created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking here. There is no custom DataTables filtering logic in the code in your question. There is some logic which builds a URL string - is that what you are asking about? Can you [edit] your question to clarify the problem?

Comment: Also, you are using `serverSide: true`, so changing the URL is not typically the way to pass request data from the DataTable to your server (if that is what you are trying to do). Instead you would use the Ajax `data` option. But again, I am guessing because I do not understand the question.

Comment: Please check MODIFIED . I hope that is clear what I want...

Comment: No, that does not really clarify things for me, it just summarizes/repeats the information that is already in the question - but thank you for trying. My best guess is: Don't use a modified URL to submit your filter data to the server. Use DataTables, by using its [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data#Examples) option. See the examples which use the function form, for example: `"data": function ( d ) { d.extra_search = $('#extra').val(); }`.

Comment: Thanks! That is just what I searched!